# Grails report generation issue with saxon

Tags: xslt, grails, testing, junit

When I run my grails tests, I get this error : I researched a lot about this issue but I cannot resolve it. I looked up many forums and common theme looked like the grails junitrunner is trying use saxon parse instead of xalan and it is causing this error. The report generation does not work. Did anyone faced this issue? 
I have saxon libraries in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile 'net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:8.7'
compile 'net.sf.saxon:saxon-xpath:8.7'
```

I noticed that when I manually run xsl transformation on my generated xml using `grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\saxon\junit-frames.xsl` it works fine but it gives me error when I run using `grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\junit-frames.xsl`. Interestingly in the error you see the former file being used ! Not sure what to make of this ??

```
[junitreport] Processing C:\git\project\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\akulkarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1\null217655770
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet C:\Grails\grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] : Warning! Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
[junitreport] C:\Grails\grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\junit-frames.xsl:16: Fatal Error! Unknown extension element
[junitreport] Failed to process C:\git\project\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml
[junitreport] Processing C:\git\project\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Users\akulkarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1\null660122935
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet C:\Grails\grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\saxon\junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] C:\Grails\grails-2.2.3\src\resources\tests\saxon\junit-frames.xsl:19: Fatal Error! Resolved URL is malformed Cause: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
[junitreport] Failed to process C:\git\project\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml
| Error Exception occurred trigger event [TestProduceReports]: Errors while applying transformations: Fatal error during transformation
Fatal error during transformation
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.handleTransformationError(XSLTProcess.java:1273)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.AggregateTransformer.transform(AggregateTransformer.java:264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator.execute(XMLResultAggregator.java:158)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:260)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.report.junit.JUnitReportProcessor$_receiveGrailsBuildEvent_closure1.doCall(JUnitReportProcessor.groovy:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.with(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:220)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$594.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.report.junit.JUnitReportProcessor.receiveGrailsBuildEvent(JUnitReportProcessor.groovy:28)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.triggerEvent(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.triggerEvent(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener$triggerEvent.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:55)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsEvents_groovy:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1128)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1084)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1128)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1084)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:729)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:769)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:466)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:410)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:374)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: Fatal error during transformation
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.fatalError(TraXLiaison.java:517)
.
.
.
```

my version of Grails is 2.2.3. and Java version is "1.7.0_51" and groovy is 2.2.2.

Comment: Still not resolved :( .. any help please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to generate reports was using this grails target

```
"grails -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl  "
```

which I would hate to do  as
1. referring com.sun.* package
2. why I should explicitly set this ? 
(just wondering if it will cause any issues in future with my project as I use saxon as my xml default parser and will the above target line be set as a system property ?)